# JavaFX's Tooltip showDuration doesn't work

Tags: java, javafx, tooltip

I want to display a tooltip inside a TextField when user copies data from it to notify him that it happened and so there is my code.

```java
public class TestController {
    @FXML private TextField textField;
    private final Clipboard clipboard;
    private ContextMenu menu;
    private MenuItem menuCopy;

    @FXML protected void initialize() {
        clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
        menu = new ContextMenu();

        menuCopy = new MenuItem("Copy");
        menuCopy.setOnAction(this::copy);

        textField.setContextMenu(menu);
    }

    private void copy(ActionEvent event) {
        final ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        if(((TextField) menu.getUserData()).getSelectedText().length() == 0)
            content.putString(((TextField) menu.getUserData()).getText());
        else
            content.putString(((TextField) menu.getUserData()).getSelectedText());
        clipboard.setContent(content);

        Point2D p = ((TextField) menu.getUserData()).localToScreen(0,0);
        Tooltip test = new Tooltip("Copied");
        test.setShowDuration(new Duration(2000));
        test.show(((TextField) menu.getUserData()), p.getX(), p.getY());
    }
}
```

But the `setShowDuration` doesn't seem to work. It will be displayed forever.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you install a `Tooltip` via [`Tooltip#install(Node,Tooltip)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Tooltip.html#install(javafx.scene.Node,javafx.scene.control.Tooltip))<sup>1</sup> there are three event handlers added to the given `Node`, all related to mouse events. It is these event handlers that implement the `showDelay` and `showDuration` functionality. This is done internally by using `Timeline`s. However, when you manually show a `Tooltip` via one of its `show` methods you completely bypass this behavior<sup>2</sup>. In other words, your `Tooltip` has the same functionality as any other `PopupControl`.

If you want to manually display a `Tooltip` and have it disappear after a specified amount of time you'll have to implement that yourself. Here's a *proof-of-concept*:

```java
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class NotifyingTextField extends TextField {

  private final Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip("Copied contents to clipboard");
  private final PauseTransition hideAnimation = new PauseTransition();

  {
    hideAnimation.durationProperty().bind(tooltip.showDurationProperty());
    hideAnimation.setOnFinished(e -> tooltip.hide());
    tooltip.setShowDuration(Duration.seconds(2.0));
  }

  @Override
  public void copy() {
    var selectedText = getSelectedText();
    if (!selectedText.isEmpty()) {
      super.copy();

      var point = localToScreen(0, 0);
      tooltip.show(this, point.getX(), point.getY());
      hideAnimation.playFromStart();
    } 
  }
}
```

Of course, you may be able to find a third-party library that offers a ready-made solution.

---

<sup>1. Even setting properties such as `Control#tooltip` or `Tab#tooltip` will delegate to `#install(Node,Tooltip)`.</sup>
<sup>2. This is true even if the `Tooltip` is installed. Manually calling `show` bypasses all the functionality added by the mouse event handlers.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the way you are implementing it, I tried it and it works for me

```
PasswordField pf = new PasswordField();
Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip("Your password must be\nat least 8 characters in length");
tooltip.setShowDuration(new Duration(2000));
pf.setTooltip(tooltip);
```

If this doesn't work with you try to help us to help you by providing snippet of your code that I can test without adding anything to it

Comment: setting a tooltip like that will display the tooltip when I hover over the textfield and I want to display it when context menu item is pressed. I will update my main post in a bit with more code.